# USB driver crash after enable Hyper V

Tags: usb, hyper-v

every time i turn it on and restart/turn on computer, USB driver crash with error code 10 or code 43 ( so i have to diable and enable them every time and it's annoying :( )

i use visual studio 2013 with winphone sdk so i really cant turn off hyper V :( i found this problem here but it's seem like there's no solution to fix it :(

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/991e94d9-359f-4f81-960b-7c4e8c9e768f/usb-controller-crash-on-intel-mobile-6-chipset?forum=w8itprohardware

btw, sorry for my bad english :P

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue.
Disabling and re-enabling the controllers restores functionality.